# For loop in command line runs bash script reading from text file line by line

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script which asks for two arguments with a space between them. Now I would like to automate filling out the prompt in the command line with reading from a text file. The text file contains a list with the argument combinations.

So something like this in the command line I think;

```
for line in 'cat text.file' ; do script.sh ; done
```

Can this be done? What am I missing/doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check my answer here for using a for loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222418/5443139

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `while` loop is probably what you need. Put the space separated strings in the file `text.file` :

```
cat text.file
bingo yankee
bravo delta
```

Then write the script in  question like below.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r arg1 arg2
do
 /path/to/your/script.sh "$arg1" "$arg2"
done<text.file
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I reference to this answer in my own.

Answer (score 1):

`'cat text.file'` is a string literal, `$(cat text.file)` would expand to output of command however `cat` is useless because bash can read file using redirection, also with quotes it will be treated as a single argument and without it will split at space tab and newlines.

Bash syntax to read a file line by line, but will be slow for big files

```
while IFS= read -r line; do ... "$line"; done < text.file
```

- unsetting IFS for read command preserves leading spaces
- `-r` option preserves `\`

another way, to read whole file is `content=$(<file)`, note the `<` inside the command substitution. so a creative way to read a file to array, each element a non-empty line:

```
read_to_array () {
    local oldsetf=${-//[^f]} oldifs=$IFS
    set -f
    IFS=$'\n' array_content=($(<"$1")) IFS=$oldifs
    [[ $oldsetf ]]||set +f
}

read_to_array "file"
for element in "${array_content[@]}"; do ...; done
```

- `oldsetf` used to store current `set -f` or `set +f` setting
- `oldifs` used to store current `IFS`
- `IFS=$'\n'` to split on newlines (multiple newlines will be treated as one)
- `set -f` avoid glob expansion for example in case line contains single `*`
- note `()` around `$()` to store the result of splitting to an array

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you might look into breaking the larger blob of code into a more readable format (perhaps shell script format) since it seems apparent that the OP is new to shell code and best practices. This will make it a bit easier for him/her to read your solution. Also note that `$(<file)` will load the entire file into memory. This is fine for smaller files but not so much for larger files.

Comment: @Yokai thank you for your feedback i've changed to a function also to be easier to use

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use `for` to read files line by line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ARGS= 
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ARGS="${ARGS} ${line}"
done < ./text.file

script.sh "$ARGS"
```

This would add each line to a variable which then is used as the arguments of your script.

Comment: mywiki doesn't seem to know about safe practices of using for loops by utilizing double quotes to preserve literal strings and file names with spaces/special characters. Even if it isn't the most efficient practice, it can still be done while avoiding the errors mentioned in the wiki. A while loop is the best route to take here though so I agree with your answer solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to create a solution determined by the literal of what you ask for (using a for loop and parsing lines from a file) I would use iterations determined by the number of lines in the file (if it isn't too large).

Assuming each line has two strings separated by a single space (to be used as positional parameters in your script:

```
file="$1"
f_count="$(wc -l < $file)"
for line in $(seq 1 $f_count)
do

    script.sh $(head -n $line $file | tail -n1) && wait

done
```

You may have a much better time using [sjsam's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222246/5443139) solution however.